# Why am I not able to view the changes made to a jsp file without restarting JBoss server?

Tags: jsp, jboss, jboss6.x, netbeans-8, jboss-eap-6

I'm using jboss-eap-6.2 and Netbeans 8.0.2 for my development activity and wanted my web application to reflect the changes that have been made to the JSP file without having to restart the JBoss server.

I added the following tag to my `standalone.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
      <jsp-configuration development="true" />
</configuration>
```

under this tag:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
```

I have also added the following snippet in my `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
     <param-value>1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I cleared the tmp folder and restarted the JBoss server but still I do not see the changes getting reflected. I went through some of the questions on the same topic on stackoverflow and these are the changes that I got from the answers to such question. Appreciate any kind of help on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using standalone mode you can redeploy your `war` or `ear` at any time without restarting JBoss and that will pick up your JSP changes.

If you have a `deployment-scanner` `scan-interval` configured in your JBoss `standalone.xml` file as such:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
  <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="3"/>
</subsystem>
```

and deploy your `war` by placing it in an exploded form to the `deployments` directory of the JBoss instance, then you can deploy it by creating an empty trigger marker file `my.war.dodeploy`. The deployment scanner will pick this up and deploy the `war` along with your JSP modifications. Once deployed JBoss will create a file `my.war.deployed`.  To redeploy after modifying the JSP recreate the `my.war.dodeploy` trigger marker file again.

Alternatively you can use the CLI or the Web Console to redeploy your war as required.